# error MSB4086: A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(MSBuildVersion)" that evaluates to "" instead of a number

Tags: azure, nuget, continuous-deployment, kudu, compiler-services

Trying to deploy the project with Azure Kudu (reading from a BitBucket repo) I get the following error in Deployment Center within Azure Portal...

This error happened with all the latest versions of [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) NuGet package. The only version that worked was [3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/3.0.0) from 5 months ago.

Anyone knows what's the cause of this? Is Azure Kudu not yet updated?

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0.23107.0 built by: D14REL' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin'.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.1.1.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.compilers/3.1.1/microsoft.net.compilers.3.1.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.compilers/3.1.1/microsoft.net.compilers.3.1.1.nupkg 937ms
Installing Microsoft.Net.Compilers 3.1.1.
Adding package 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.1.1' to folder 'D:\home\site\repository\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.1.1' to folder 'D:\home\site\repository\packages'

NuGet Config files used:
    D:\local\UserProfile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    D:\home\.nuget\
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installed:
    1 package(s) to packages.config projects
D:\home\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.1.1\tools\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets(63,60): error MSB4086: A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(MSBuildVersion)" that evaluates to "" instead of a number, in condition "$(MSBuildVersion) >= 16.1.0". [D:\home\site\repository\MyCompany\MyCompany.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\MyCompany\MyCompany.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d727f56aa60788";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository\.\\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\84.10807.4030\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

**### EDIT ###**

I also opened [an issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3019) @ Kudu GitHub repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve had a similar issue with a kudu deployment and typescript versions. The basic issue seem to be that kudu is on its way out in favour of Azure DevOps so some dependencies of msbuild are becoming out of date. These are three options that might help you resolve the issue:

1. Switch to Azure DevOps - you’ll have access to various build agents and much more control over what they are capable of, but generally they’ll just be more up to date
2. Amend your build script - this is the script that kudu uses and you can customise it and then put it in source control, see [this kudu doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) for more info. Looks like you’re targeting msbuild 14 but I’m pretty sure 15 should be available and you can point your build script at this and/or make other tweaks
3. Process some of your build offline, ie before committing - this was my temporary solution with typescript, I was able to transpile to JavaScript and commit the js meaning I could disable typescript processing for kudu

It may also help to dig around in the targets file referenced in your log and trace back where the problem starts through the various msbuild conditions in that file. You can see all this by exploring via a command prompt in kudu.